# How do I turn off the sound Windows 10 makes when I plug in headphones?

Tags: windows, audio, headphones

I usually wear headphones at my computer. Every time I plug them in, however, a deafening sound plays through them. How can I remove this sound?

p.s.
This is less important, and if you don't know don't bother. Whenever I reboot my PC the sound level gets reset to 100. Is it possible to get it to save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn off the notifications, access Win 10 Settings - click the notifications icon in the taskbar’s system tray area, then click “All settings”.
In “Sound” click on the “Sounds” tab and you can either remove system sounds completely, or configure them individually. Find "Notifications", click the scrolling menu at the bottom of the control panel next to the “Test” button, scroll to the top and select “None”, and click “Apply” or “OK”.

Comment: +Hans Folkner My ears thank you :-)